# For cycle setting from the n-1 position to the 1

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I'm solving a specific matrix following a theoretical code from a book.

My issue is pretty simple I set that my last value from the one column matrix X is equal to the last one of my one column matrix Z.

After that I do for cycle where I need to pick the second to last until the first.

I don't know how to right this in code way

The book has " i = n-1,....,1 "

If it was i = 1, ....., n-1 it would be easy.

I tried the i=(n-1):1
And this i=(n-1):-1:1

Doesn't work. Returns has empty

To be clear to code is the follow:

```
i=n-1:1

x(i,1)=z(i,1)-u(i,i+1)*x(i+1,1)
```

So if n=4, i already have x(4).

So X(3)=z(3)-u(3,4)*x(4,1)

More of the code:

```
n=4;
Matrix=[2,-1,0,0,1;-1, 2,-1,0,0;0,-1,2,-1,0;0,0,-1,2,1];
u=eye(4,4);
l(1,1)=Matrix(1,1);
u(1,2)=Matrix(1,2)/l(1,1);
z(1,1)=Matrix(1,n+1)/l(1,1);

for i=2:n-1
  l(i,i-1)=Matrix(i,i-1);
  l(i,i)=Matrix(i,i)-l(i,i-1)*u(i-1,i); 
  u(i,i+1)=Matrix(i,i+1)/l(i,i);    
  z(i,1)=(Matrix(i,n+1)-l(i,i-1)*z(i-1,1))/l(i,i); 
endfor
l(n,n-1)=Matrix(n,n-1);
l(n,n)=Matrix(n,n)-l(n,n-1)*u(n-1,n)
z(n,1)=(Matrix(n,n+1)-l(n,n-1)*z(n-1,1))/l(n,n)
x(n,1)=z(n,1);

for i=(1-n):-1:1
  x(i,1)=z(i,1)-u(i,i+1)*x(i+1,1);
endfor
```

Comment: Can you show more of the program?  Is this in a for loop: If not try i=n-1:-1:1

Comment: @ClintonWinant yes, i editted the post with the full code since it isn't that big and gives a notion of where z and u comes from. U being upper matrix and L lower.

The code i posted has the n-1:-1:1 try. It doesnt return any value.

Comment: @ClintonWinant just saw my error, christ lol. Everything is fine solved. If you don't see it, it was because i set (1-n)